# Help with Mathematical Formulation for VRP with Specific Constraints

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing

I am currently working on a Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) with a set of specific constraints. I have a total of 19 nodes, each representing a customer location, and a depot. There are also 7 pickers available to fulfill the pick up requirements. The problem has the following characteristics:

I have a distance matrix between all 19 nodes and the depot.
Each node has an associated demand representing the amount to be picked up.
The pickers have a limited capacity of 25 units each.
**The capacity of each picker is less than the demand at every node**, necessitating **multiple trips**.

I am seeking assistance in formulating this problem mathematically. Specifically, I need help defining the constraints to ensure that the pickers efficiently complete their tasks **while considering capacity limitations and multiple trips necessity**.

**Data:**

- Distance matrix: A 20x20 matrix representing distances between nodes and the depot.
- Demand: A list of 19 demand values, one for each node.
- Picker capacity: 25 units for each picker.
- Number of pickers: 7.

**Goal:**
Minimize the total distance traveled by the pickers while satisfying the pick up demands and capacity constraints.

Comment: Search for “split delivery vehicle routing problem”

Comment: I agree with @RobPratt's comment. Problem also seems related to a simplified version of the "dial-a-ride problem"

Comment: Do the pickers start at one depot, travel to another, perform the pick-up and return? Or does the pick-up occur at the start?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with LP but it isn't entirely straightforward.

Right out the gate, ignore `n_pickers = 7`. Your objective is only on total distance and not total time, which is a very different creature; so we can imagine that an optimal system smells the same regardless of whether you have one picker or 700.

With

- picker capacity $c = 25$,
- node count $n = 19$, and
- node demand $d_i > c \; \forall i$,

There is an important pre-solve step - run a fixed number of visits to each node at full capacity equal to $$ \lfloor\frac {d_i} c \rfloor $$

After these fixed visits, we can guarantee that the remaining $0 \le d_i < c \; \forall i$.

Then you'll need distinct circuits. It's easy to prove that the maximum number of non-degenerate circuits is $n$.

With

- graph edges $e_{ijk}$ (source $i$, dest $j$ and circuit $k$),
- graph node visit assignments $a_{ik}$,
- units picked up per node visit $u_{ik}$, and
- distances $\delta_{ij}$:

Care must be taken when defining $e$. No $(i, i)$ is allowed, but *some* matrix transposition must be allowed. The only situation where we permit an edge to be traversed twice is if it's from the depot to a node and directly back again; so a sample solution could end up looking like

```
node_b   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
node_a                                                       
0       NaN  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1       0.0  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2       1.0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
6       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0
8       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0
9       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
10      0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

with `NaN` where there is no edge assignment defined. (Notice the subtrip in the above - more on that in a minute.)

Minimize the distance objective:
$$\sum_{ijk} e_{ijk} \delta_{ij}$$

Subject to the following.

The sum of visit units for each circuit must not exceed capacity:

$$\sum_i u_{ik} \le c \; \forall k$$

The sum of visit units over all circuits for each node must equal the node's demand left over from after the unconditional trips:

$$\sum_k u_{ik} = d_i \; \forall i$$

If the visit is assigned, at least one unit must be picked up, and vice versa; here a suitable $M > d_i$:

$$a_{ik} \le u_{ik} \le M a_{ik}$$

Within each circuit, for each node, the number of associated edges must either be 2 if the visit is assigned (one ingress edge, one egress edge), or 0 otherwise (notably this is conditional whereas traditional TSP is unconditional):

$$\sum_{j} e_{ijk} = 2 a_{ik} \; \forall i,k $$

Specific to the depot, for each circuit, the number of egress (and, separately, ingress) edges must be 1 if there is any visit assigned in the circuit, or 0 otherwise:

$$\frac 1 n \sum_i a_{ik} \le \sum_i e_{i0k} \le \sum_i a_{ik} \; \forall k$$
$$\frac 1 n \sum_j a_{jk} \le \sum_j e_{0jk} \le \sum_j a_{jk} \; \forall k$$

All of this will not be enough; you need subtrip elimination.  Read e.g. [Dantzig cutting-plane](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/methods/dfj/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

In Timefold (open source, java), start from the capacitated VRP quickstarts ([see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaP6rgvElhc)).

One not-very-sophisticated way to solve it:

1. If a visit has 40 units, split it up into 40 visits at the same location.
2. Create a src/main/resources/solverConfig.xml (see vaccination quickstart how) and configure ListChangeMoveSelector and ListSwapMoveSelector together with the normal change, swap and tailSwap moves. [See docs.](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#listMoveSelectors)

---

A much more sophisticated way would be to not split up the demands, to drop capacity as a constraint and instead introduce a shadow variable "Visit.unitsCollectedThisFar" (and Visit.arrivalTime like in VRPTW) to force the pickers to go back-and-forth to the depot in the middle of a picking. This would scale much better in case you want to handle thousands of pickers.